# Null values in My SQL query

Tags: mysql

My Query is

```
SELECT i.status,i.amount_total, i.id,sc.category as category,us.fname as name,us.company as company,
(SELECT transaction_id FROM invoice_payments WHERE invoice_payments.invoice_id = i.id) as transaction_id ,
(SELECT created  FROM invoice_payments WHERE invoice_payments.invoice_id = i.id and invoice_payments.created BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01') as created 
FROM invoices i
inner JOIN 
users as us ON us.id = i.client_id 
inner JOIN subscriptioncategory as sc ON sc.user_id = us.id
```

and my result is

[image]

in the Created column, i should not get the null values. are there any simple query to fix it.

Comment: simply add created IS NOT NULL in where statement

Comment: wont work, throws ambiguity error

Comment: That's why you need to use invoice_payments.created in the subselect, not just created in main select...

Comment: @user1100671 The answer below worked for me . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join all tables with `inner join`:

```
SELECT i.status,i.amount_total, i.id,sc.category as category,us.fname as name,us.company as company,
ip.transaction_id,
ip1.created 
FROM invoices i
inner JOIN 
users as us ON us.id = i.client_id 
inner JOIN subscriptioncategory as sc ON sc.user_id = us.id
join invoice_payments ip on ip.invoice_id = i.id 
join invoice_payments ip1 WHERE ip1.invoice_id = i.id and ip1.created BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
```